# How do I correctly mark an item as selected in the NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a navigation drawer in my app. Every Entry in the list of the NavigationDrawer represents one navigation graph. I want to mark the element in which the user currently is.

I managed to get the item to be marked after it is selected and until the visible fragment changes (even if the new fragment is still in the same navGraph). I did that by setting a NavigationItemSelectedListener using `NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener listener)`. Inside this listeners `onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean` function, I do: `item.isChecked = true`.

The problem with this is that the item is unchecked after the app starts and the item looses it's checked state as soon as the fragment changes (even if the navGraph doesn't change). How do I do this correctly?

I have also tried to set `android:checked="true"` in the xml declaration of the menu item I want to be checked when the app starts. It doesn't seem to do anything.
I have also tried to set `navView.setCheckedItem(R.id.main_nav_option_one)` in the Activity's onCreate function. Again, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer)? about setting up navigation drawer with a nav controller

Comment: I hadn't. But now that I have, I just have different problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem.

The most important change I had to make is mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer). I had to give my menu items the same ID as the ID of the navGraphs. When I did this, I removed my `NavigationItemSelectedListener` because it was interfering with the automatically generated navigation. Without a `NavigationItemSelectedListener` I could no longer handle a navigation item being clicked, that doesn't have a corresponding element in the navGraph. However I was able to fix it, by adding the `NavigationItemSelectedListener` back in, and making the correct calls to `NavController.navigate()` for every element in the list.

TL;DR:
I had to set the menu item IDs to be the same as my navGraph IDs and make the navigation calls myself anyway in the `NavigationItemSelectedListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
        navView.getMenu().getItem(index).setChecked(true)
```

in the fragment's onResume?

Comment: how do I get the navView inside the fragment?